# Laravel 5.0.34 database seeding error with tinker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-seeding

I am following [this](https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/6) laracast tutorial and as I key in this command in tinker:

```
factory('App\Flyer')->make();
```

I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function factory() in eval()'d cod1

My php version locally installed is `5.4.38`

So how do I get rid of this error?

**PS**: I want to avoid upgrading laravel at this stage as it would require me to update my php as well. So looking for some other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Model factories were added in Laravel 5.1 so it's obvious it won't work in Laravel 5.0.*

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.1

Comment: So is there any way otherwise to somehow seed the database with random data in 5.0.x?

Comment: @rahulserver You could use the [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library directly (Laravel Model Factories use it behind the scenes). [This article](http://laraveldaily.com/generating-fake-seeds-data-with-faker-package/) explains how you can use it.

Comment: @rahulserver As Bogdan said, you can use [Faker library ](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#basic-usage) which is used in Laravel 5.1 for factories